# Ajax GET is getting called twice (in Endless Scroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, pagination

I have an endless scrolling made by ajax and jQuery. It's using the items paginated in Controller (Laravel5), getting it with ajax.

Everything works fine, however I have a problem. When I hit the bottom of the page, it makes an ajax call twice. I suspect it's because of the `setInterval` because when I change the time, it affects exactly that part.

```
// Creates the pagination pages [<[1]2]3]>]
{!! $boxes->render() !!}

// Html
        <input type="hidden" id="page" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" id="max_page" value="{{{ $boxes-id }}}" />
        <div id="end_of_page" class="center">
            <hr/>
            <span>End of the feed.</span>
```

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var didScroll = false;

       $(window).scroll(function() { //watches scroll of the window
             didScroll = true;
       });


       //Sets an interval so your window.scroll event doesn't fire constantly. This waits for the user to stop scrolling for not even a second and then fires the pageCountUpdate function (and then the getPost function)
    setInterval(function() {
        if (didScroll){
           didScroll = false;
           if(($(document).height()-$(window).height())-$(window).scrollTop() < 10){
                  pageCountUpdate();
            }
        }
    }, 250);
```

When I change 250 to 5000 for example, it gives a time in between, but this is not what I want to make. I want to make the call only one time once I hit the bottom, maybe disable it with a boolean variable, and then reactivate it after new elements load (on ajax success state), but I couldn't figure it out where to put the blocking variable.

```
//Continuing

    function pageCountUpdate(){
          var page = parseInt($('#page').val());
          var max_page = parseInt($('#max_page').val());

          if(page < max_page){
              $('#page').val(page+1);
              getPosts();
              $('#end_of_page').hide();
          } else {
              $('#end_of_page').fadeIn();
          }
      }

    function getPosts(){
        var data = { "page": $('#page').val() }
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",

                //Classic ajax call

                beforeSend: function(){
                ..}
                complete: function(){
                ..}
                success: function(){
                ..}    
        });
    }

 } 
});
```

**Update**: Regarding to John Resig's example mentioned in comments, I need to use `var outerPane = $details.find(".details-pane-outer"),
    didScroll = false;`. I think not having this part creates my problem, but I couldn't figure out where to choose with `find()` method.

Comment: Using an interval doesn't really seem like a good way to debounce an event ?

Comment: What's the best way to achieve this? What do you suggest to use instead of using interval?

Comment: While I'm sure he's not the only one to advocate this pattern, John Resig recommends it in [this post](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/) to ease the call.

Comment: Where do I need to set outerPane? `var outerPane = $details.find(".details-pane-outer"),`. What do I need to select with `$details.find(".details-pane-outer")`? I tried `var outerPane = $('#content'),` but doesn't change anything

Comment: @Phix - then it's probably fine. I've never seen it done like that before, and having a function that runs 4 times every second, always, just didn't seem like a good idea. I would have used a timeout inside the event handler instead, but that's just me.

Comment: As for the answer to this question, just add a condition that doesn't use the debounce when the bottom is reached, but fires a function with a timeout disabling it for a few seconds.

Comment: @adeneo Can you please show me an example?

Comment: Not really. I can't easily replicate your code and the way data is fetched from the server.

Comment: This code works well. The only problem of it is that it either needs `var outerPane` part or setTimeout. I am not asking you to try out the code, but just give me a path on where should I place the timeout? Do I need to call `myVar = setTimeout(alertFunc, 3000);` in ajax beforeSend state  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apart from your weird setinterval structure (just move the code into the scroll event, without an interval).

It seems that the scroll event is called multiple times inside the last 10 pixels of the bottom of the page. So while scrolling to the bottom, at 9 px away form the bottom, the event is fired which loads more posts. But even before the new posts are loaded, in the meanwhile you scroll a little further which again fires the scroll event. This makes your posts load twice or even more than twice.

To solve this you can add a simple boolean switch that makes sure that the posts don't get loaded again when they're already being loaded. Something like:

```
var loading=false;
function onReachScrollLimit(){
    if(loading){return;}
    loading=true;
    load_new_posts();
}
function load_new_posts(){
    //insert the posts
    loading=false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean moving setInterval into `$(window).scroll(function() {`? And, should I also put `pageCountUpdate();` inside `load_new_posts()`? . I got so confused adapting it to me code. Sorry that I'm new to jquery.

Comment: Ah I thought you understood the code that you posted. First off, try to understand everything what is happening, it will help you learn javascript. setInterval is a function that runs code every X milliseconds. So your code summarized does the following: every time when you scroll, variable didScroll switches to true, and on the next interval (every 250 milliseconds) you check where it is true, and then check if it's at the end of the page. This method is not very efficient as javascript is constantly evaluating this interval function (I CONTINUE IN MY NEXT COMMENT)

Comment: So better to evaluate whether the scrollposition is close to the bottom inside the scroll event, not in the interval. What you do with pagecountupdate is up to you, it's separate from the issue you had. I presume it updates a counter somewhere? You probably should run it once you insert new posts into the page